# Implementing onCompletionExceptionHandler for Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have been trying to implement unsuccessfully onCompletionExceptionHandler to hide a warning printed by the GenericFileOnCompletion component because of a file renaming error (where the file originally existed, but was removed by the time of the GenericFileOnCompletion). Are there any good links that give an example as to how to do this?? Or an example??

I have tried to do:

```
from("file://C:/temp?onCompletionExceptionHandler=MyHandler")
```

But this gives me a FailedToCreateRouteException.

Comment: You are not giving the file name ? can you try `file://C:/temp/?onCompletionExceptionHandler=MyHandler`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the `#beanId` syntax, eg

```
from("file://C:/temp?onCompletionExceptionHandler=#MyHandler")
```

Where `MyHandler` is the bean name (bean id) of the bean that implements the `ExceptionHandler`.

There is a bit of documentation about this here: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html